# Weird compile-time error only when class is generic

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, inner-classes

The following code compiles fine:

```
public class Test {

    public static interface A<Y> {
        public B<Y> foo();
    }
    public static interface B<Y> extends A<Y> {
        public A<Y> bar();
    }

    private static class Impl
        implements A, B
    {
        public B foo() {
            return this;
        }
        public A bar() {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

But when a generic parameter is introduced to top-level class Test the code no longer compiles:

```
public class Test<X> {

    public static interface A<Y> {
        public B<Y> foo();
    }
    public static interface B<Y> extends A<Y> {
        public A<Y> bar();
    }

    private static class Impl
        implements A, B
    {
        public B foo() {
            return this;
        }
        public A bar() {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

The error I get is:

> The interface A cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: Test.A and Test.A

What causes this weird compilation error? What can be done to fix it?

By the way, I use eclipse and Java 1.8.0_144.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, also your Impl shouldn't use raw type, you need to specify the Y, like `implements A<Integer>, B<Integer>`

Comment: @azro What version of Java are you using? What compiler implementation are you using?

Comment: Nit: interfaces are always static, no need to declare them static explicitly.

Comment: @Andy Turner that may well be; the code is certainly not pretty or even remotely sensible in its current iteration because I have been fiddling with it for quite some time trying to find out why it does not compile.

Comment: Does it compile with `javac`? Eclipse has its own compiler (or at least used to have).

Comment: I think this is a compiler bug. `X` shouldn't affect a static nested class.

Comment: It does indeed not happen when I use javac. This seems to be an eclipse compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested by Andy Turner in the comments this is a compiler bug. When compiling with the command line and javac both versions compile just fine. Only within eclipse (using the build in eclipse compiler) does the error occur.

The eclipse version where the bug occured is indeed quite outdated:

Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)

Build id: 20170620-1800

The bug appears to have been fixed in later versions of eclipse.